# Calling system from a post in sinatra

Tags: ruby, bash, sinatra

I  made a very small app for the raspberry pi, that uses Sinatra:
https://github.com/khebbie/SpeakPi

The app lets the user input some text in a textarea and asks Google to create an mp3 file for it.

In there I have a shell script called speech2.sh which calls Google and plays the mp3 file:

```
#!/bin/bash
say() { 
wget -q -U Mozilla -O out.mp3 "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=da&q=$*";

local IFS=+;omxplayer out.mp3; 
}
say $*
```

When I call speech.sh from the commandline like so:

```
./speech2.sh %C3%A6sel
```

It pronounces `%C3%A6` like the danish letter 'æ', which is correct!

I call speech2.sh from a Sinatra route like so:

```
post '/say' do
  message = params[:body]
  system('/home/pi/speech2.sh '+ message)
  haml :index
end
```

And when I do so Google pronounces some very weird chars like 'a broken pipe...' which is wrong!

All chars `a-z` are pronounced correctly

I have tried some URL encoding and decoding, nothing worked.

I tried outputting the message to the command-line and it was exactly `"%C3%A6"`  that certainly did not make sense.
Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

To Sum it up and simplify - if I type like so in bash:

```
./speech2.sh %C3%A6sel
```

It works

If I start an irb session and type:

```
system('/home/pi/speech2.sh', '%C3%A6sel')
```

It does not work!

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding a string e.g. `message = "%C3%A6"` in the route to check that it's not something to do with the params object?

Comment: I did that, I hardcoded this in the route, and it pronounced it the wrong way. So this makes it clear that it is the call to system that fails...

Comment: Have you tried putting the magic comment for utf at the top of your ruby file? e.g. `# encoding: UTF-8` And which version of Ruby and Bash are you running?

Comment: Tried that did not work. ruby 1.9.3p327. GNU bash, version 4.2.36(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)

Comment: You could try sticking an `echo` in the shell script to see what it receives, and I'd consider wrapping it in quotes so that there's no interpolation by the shell (for some reason?!) e.g. `system("/home/pi/speech2.sh '#{message}'")`. It's more rubyish this way too :)

Comment: Not working either :-( Thanks for trying. As I wrote in my question I already tried echoing the parameter, and it looks right.

Comment: By the way thanks for being so persistent in trying to help me :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21896/discussion-between-iain-and-khebbie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is handling UTF-8, make sure that the encoding remains right the way through the process by adding the `# encoding: UTF-8` magic comment at the top of the Ruby script and passing the `ie=UTF-8` parameter in the query string when calling Google Translate.